# Jquery click value check not working

Tags: php, jquery

I have a function that on click add/removes stuff from a SQL database.

I do a condition to check if it is refering to an add or remove and execute the code.

the add function works perfectly, but the remove not and its the same code, am i missing something obvious? And is this the best way to do this?

jquery:

```
//add card from list
$("#listcards a").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('add').length > 1) {
      var value = $(this).attr('add');
      $.post('searchc.php',{add:value}, function(data){
         $("#add_result").html(data);
       });
       return false;
    }
});

//remove card from list
$("#listcards a").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('rem').length > 1) {
      var value = $(this).attr('rem');
      $.post('searchc.php',{rem:value}, function(data){
         $("#add_result").html(data);
       });
       return false;
    }
});
```

html code:

```
<form id="listcards" method="post">
    <input type='hidden' id='lcard' name='lcard' value=''>
    <div>
        bla bla -> imagem no + ? ou por algum efeito css<a href="" add="bla bla">+</a> | <a href="" rem="bla bla">-</a><br>
        coiso coiso <a href="" add="coiso coiso">+</a> | <a href="" rem="coiso coiso">-</a><br>
    </div>
</form>
```

Do i also need to be in a form for the POST or a div would work too?

Comment: no need to be "in a form" (as you put it) to send an ajax request. There does not need to be any connection to a HTML element at all in order to do that. You _can_ handle a form's submit event and override the default behaviour so that it uses ajax instead to submit the form's data, but it's not a requirement. You can trigger an ajax call by any means you see fit, and send any data you want - which is what you're already doing.

Comment: And what is meant by "not working"? What debugging steps have you taken? Have you checked for errors in your browser's developer console?

Comment: You should have to use class for this

Comment: @ADyson first thing i did was putting an alert on the if condition for the rem value to see if it was entering the condition. it was not.

tried changing the if's order to check if jquery for some reason only checked the first if on a click and did not check the others. it did not.

edit: never thought of check developer's console. will do.

and take out the form too, thanks.

edit2: tried the developers console but no feedback was given (oppened it and clicked the link, is just that?)

by not working i mean, when i press the add it works, when i press the removes it doesn't work.

Comment: @AnandPandey add another class inside the <a> and add that to the click selector?

Comment: @ADyson changed the order on the jquery script and the second one stopped working. So there should be something related to that. but i don't get is why.

Comment: @JoséMoreira  you can combine both code into one.check my answer for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two click handlers for the same elements, which could be causing a problem. You don't need to run both sets of code for each `<a>` element. Instead give the elements a class to show exactly what they do, and then limit your selectors to those elements

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="add" add="bla bla">+</a> | <a href="" class="remove" rem="bla bla">
```

Script:

```
$("#listcards a.add").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('add');
  $.post('searchc.php',{add:value}, function(data){
    $("#add_result").html(data);
  });
  return false;
});

//remove card from list
$("#listcards a.remove").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('rem');
  $.post('searchc.php',{rem:value}, function(data){
     $("#add_result").html(data);
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: yes, it works. it was indeed having 2 handlers for the same element.

Comment: @AlivetoDie thank you, will check your example too, can only have one best answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like thisi will give only remove functionality. And oif possible add ajax.

```
$("#listcards .rem").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    if($(this).length()>1) { 
    $.post('searchc.php',{rem:value}, function(data){
         $("#add_result").html(data);
       });
   return false;
}});
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you don't have any card when you're loading this page 1st time. Then you click add new & a new card get's added to your html.
Now for this newly added card, the "remove" method doesn't get bind as that was loaded on page load (when this new card element was not present). Hence your remove method is not working for newly added cards.

So to make it work, you need to bing the remove method on new cards too. You can do that by keeping you remove part in a js function which you would call in "add" part after putting new card into html.

```
function removeCard(){

// first unbind the click event for all cards if any & then bind it

  $("#listcards a").off('click'); 

//remove card from list

 $("#listcards a").click(function() {

    if($(this).attr('rem').length > 1) {
      var value = $(this).attr('rem');
      $.post('searchc.php',{rem:value}, function(data){
         $("#add_result").html(data);
       });
       return false;
    }
  });
}

And you add part should be like this:
//add card from list
$("#listcards a").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('add').length > 1) {
      var value = $(this).attr('add');
      $.post('searchc.php',{add:value}, function(data){
         $("#add_result").html(data);
         removeCard(); // adding remove method here
       });
       return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow up your code,

```
$("#listcards a").click(function() {
        var action = $(this).attr("add") ? "add" : "rem";
var value;
        if(action == "add")
              value = $(this).attr('add');
        if(action == "rem")
          value = $(this).attr('rem');
    var param = {};
    param[action] = value;
        $.post('searchc.php',param, function(data){
         $("#add_result").html(data);
       });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick function to do this
It can help you out

```
<a href="" add="coiso coiso" onclick="addthis('coiso coiso');">+</a>
<a href="" rem="coiso coiso" onclick="removethis('coiso coiso');">-</a><br>


function addthis(addthis) {
    if(addthis.length > 1) {
       alert(addthis);
    // $.post('searchc.php',{add:addthis}, function(data){
    //      $("#add_result").html(data);
    //    });
       return false;
    }
}

function removethis(remthis) {
    if(remthis.length > 1) {
       alert(remthis);
    // $.post('searchc.php',{reb:remthis}, function(data){
    //      $("#add_result").html(data);
    //    });
       return false;
    }
}
```